# Getting a pure function from a model fit

Tags: function-construction, fitting

I am looking for defining a function returning a function.
This function must return a polynomial fit. I managed to pass the function to fit as argument but i stuggle with the returned value of the function.

With the code below I get fit but this do not seem to be a pure function. This is a problem because the code after needs pure functions.

```
GetFitProba[f_Symbol, T_, V_, eta_, cut_, t_] := (
  data = Transpose[
    List[Table[i, {i, IntegerPart[cut], V}], 
     f[#, T, V, eta, t] & /@ Table[i, {i, IntegerPart[cut], V}]]];
  fit = LinearModelFit[
    data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^8, x^9, x^10, x^11, x^12},
     x];
  fit[x]
  )
```

Then I call it like that:

```
h[x_] := GetFitProba[f, T, V, eta, cut, t];
```

(where `f`, `t`, `V`, `eta`, `cut`, and `t` are well defined)

I think the problem come from the objet returned by `LinearModelFit` (which is a `FittedModel`) but I do not understand how I am supposed to managed it. I tried to return `Normal[fit]` and things like that but it didn't work.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. `fit` works like a function when applied to numbers. If you want to return a function, return `fit`.  Otherwise there are various pieces of information you can extract from `fit` using `fit["property"]`. The possible properties are documented in the `LinearModelFit` page. Always look under Details and Options.

Comment: AsI need a lot of fit of this kind, with different function (but same parameters) i want a function for lighten my code. The Pilsy's sollution works fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to boldly plunge ahead despite being unable to test directly, because why not. As you may have noticed, `fit` returns a [`FittedModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FittedModel.html) object. Most such objects have a bunch of properties that you can find by passing them a string argument; you can get a list of all such properties with `fit["Properties"]`. In this case, you want `fit["Function"]`.

```
ClearAll[GetFitProba];
GetFitProba[f_, T_, V_, eta_, cut_, t_] :=
 Module[{data = 
    Transpose[
     List[Table[i, {i, IntegerPart[cut], V}], 
      f[#, T, V, eta, t] & /@ Table[i, {i, IntegerPart[cut], V}]]],
   fit},

  fit = LinearModelFit[
    data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6, x^8, x^9, x^10, x^11, x^12},
     x];

  fit["Function"]];
```

Just as an aside, I ditched the requirement that `f` have head `Symbol`, since you might want use a pure function (with head [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html)), or even perhaps a curried "operator form" of a function like [`Lookup`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html). Also, I went ahead used [`Module`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Module.html) to make the `fit` and `data` variables local, which is good practice.

Now that you have a pure function, you can just assign it to `h` directly:

```
ClearAll[h]; 
h = GetFitProba[f, T, V, eta, cut, t];
```